# Curvature of principal bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, fibre-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

Let $(P,M,G)$ be a principal bundle with connection 1-form $\omega$. In all books I have seen so far, the curvature is defined by
\begin{equation}
F:=D_{\omega}\omega \in \Omega({P,\mathfrak{g}})
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
(D_{\omega}\omega)_p(X_1,...,X_k)=d \omega_p(X_1^H,...,X_k^H)
\end{equation}
where $X_i^H$ means the projection on the horizontal part.
However wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory_(mathematics)) states, that the curvature can be also see as
\begin{equation}
F(X_1,X_2)=[X_1^\#,X_2^\#]-[X_1,X_2]^\# \in \Omega(M,ad(P))
\end{equation}
where # denotes the horizontal lift of the vector fields.
What is the exact connection of the two definitions. How can I derive them from each other. I would also be very grateful if someone could provide a reference where the definition wikipedia uses is discussed.

Comment: Could you give a specific reference for your first version?

Comment: E.g. Mathematical gauge theory by Hamilton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll use $\Omega \in \Omega^2(P,\mathfrak{g})$ to denote the curvature tensor of $\omega$.
One way of identifying these two expressions is through Cartan's structure equation
$$\Omega = d\omega + \frac{1}{2}\omega \wedge \omega.$$
A reference is Kobayashi-Nomitsu's book, Chapter II.5;
here we use the convention
$$d \omega(X,Y) = \frac{1}{2}(X \cdot \omega(Y) - Y \cdot \omega(X) - \omega([X,Y]))$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are local sections of $TP$.

Since $\Omega$ is horizontal and $\omega$ sends horizontal sections to $0$,
we have
$$\Omega(X,Y) = \Omega(X^H,Y^H) = -\frac{1}{2}\omega([X^H,Y^H]).$$
As $[X^H,Y^H]^H = [X,Y]^H$ and $\omega$ sends any local section to its vertical part,
we have
$$\omega([X^H,Y^H]) = [X^H,Y^H] - [X^H,Y^H]^H = [X^H,Y^H] - [X,Y]^H.$$
Finally, you can compare $\Omega(X,Y)$ with $F(X,Y)$ in your question through
the canonical isomorphism from
the subspace of $\Omega^2(P,\mathfrak{g})$ consisting of $G$-equivariant horizontal 2-forms
to $\Omega^2(M,ad(P))$.

Comment: But $D_\omega\omega$ of the OP seems to be not a 2-form? As written, it has values on $k$-tuples of vector fields for all $k$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე It is a 2 form. I just wrote down the general expression for $D_{\omega} \omega$ if $\omega$ is a $k$-form

Comment: @HYL Thanks. That's what I was looking for. I am just a bit confused. The expression for $\Omega$ then needs a $-1/2$ factor which is missing in wikipedia.

Comment: There are two conventions defining $d \omega$ for a $k$-form $\omega$, according to whether there is a factor $\frac{1}{k+1}$ or not. In Kobayashi-Nomitsu's book, the factor $\frac{1}{k+1}$ is in the definition, this is why we have $\frac{1}{2}$ in the structure equation.

Comment: Thanks. Then there is maybe a mistake in the wikipedia article, because they also use the $1/2$ in the structure equation.

Comment: Sorry, I have to digest all these definitions. But it essentially means, that the curvature of $P$ is defined by the connection and the curvature of $M$. Since the horizontal subspace $T_pH$ is isomorphic to $T_pM$, the definition above tells us how much $T_pM$ and $T_qM$ differ. Or how much the actual connection of $T_pM$ and $T_qM$ differs from the flat connection

Comment: In the last line, you need to show that $[X^V, Y^V]$ and $[X^V, Y^H]$ are vertical, right?